# Frontend image slider is broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, magento

got to work on a site as a rookie, 
usualy im working in dreamweaver and do also hardcoding in html and css 
thats why i tryed to do so in magento

i went to the cms / static block section to do a change, but since then my slider on the frontside is just not working anymore. i guess the js script is broken down.
    heres the script in the cms / static block

```
<div>
<a href="/"><img src="/skin/frontend/default/theme049/slider/xxx" alt="" /></a>
<a href="/"><img src="/skin/frontend/default/theme049/slider/xxx" alt="" /></a>
<a href="/"><img src="/skin/frontend/default/theme049/slider/xxx" alt="" /></a>
<a href="/"><img src="/skin/frontend/default/theme049/slider/xxx" alt="" /></a>
<a href="/"><img src="/skin/frontend/default/theme049/slider/xxx" alt="" /></a>
<a href="/"><img src="/skin/frontend/default/theme049/slider/xxx" alt="" /></a>
</div>

<script src="/skin/frontend/default/theme049/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="/skin/frontend/default/theme049/js/coin-slider.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#coin-slider').coinslider();
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

any sugestion why it doesnt work

seen on www.ungezogen-angezogen.ch

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="coin-slider">
<a href="/"><img src="/skin/frontend/default/theme049/slider/xxx" alt="" /></a>
<a href="/"><img src="/skin/frontend/default/theme049/slider/xxx" alt="" /></a>
<a href="/"><img src="/skin/frontend/default/theme049/slider/xxx" alt="" /></a>
<a href="/"><img src="/skin/frontend/default/theme049/slider/xxx" alt="" /></a>
<a href="/"><img src="/skin/frontend/default/theme049/slider/xxx" alt="" /></a>
<a href="/"><img src="/skin/frontend/default/theme049/slider/xxx" alt="" /></a>
</div>

<script src="/skin/frontend/default/theme049/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="/skin/frontend/default/theme049/js/coin-slider.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery('#coin-slider').coinslider();
});
//]]>
</script>
```

You missed the id of the HTML element. Your `jQuery('#coin-slider')` didn't found anything.  Now will workkk uhuu